# When to push updates to REST back-end

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

This question might be to general but I'll give it go. I have a REST back-end and a React front-end using Redux, Axios and Thunk. I'm pulling data from the back-end to the front-end. I'm now about to code the part where I can edit the data in the front-end that I've pulled from the back-end. The data I'm pulling is a list of currency rates. The data consists of `currency code`, `rate` and `date`.

The data looks like this:

```
EUR    1.12    2016-10-03
USD    1.00    2016-10-03
GBP    1.29    2016-10-03
```

In the front-end I'll edit, lets say the rate for `EUR` from `1.12` to `1.14`.

1. Should I first update my `state` (which is mapped to `props`) in the
   front-end and then push the update to the REST back-end.
2. Should I first push the update to the REST back-end and then pull
   the data    again from the back-end and thereby refresh `state`?
3. Should I do it in some other way?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I prefer instant state update with rest request. If request fails, than show error message or something. You don't need reload your posted data from server in most cases.

Comment: Pull the data from your backend and load it in your editable user interface,  edit and push the data finally pull the data when go back to the user interface template if needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I first update my state (which is mapped to props) in the
>   front-end and then push the update to the REST back-end.

If you update state before pushing to server, this doesn't cover case when push fails. You first need to be sure, that server update is successful.

---

> Should I first push the update to the REST back-end and then pull the
>   data again from the back-end and thereby refresh state?

If only one client can update data at a time (if server not do changes merge on during push processing) then after push client already contains the same data as server, and you do not need to do additional pull for synchronization.